# Reactive forms setValue from @Input

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I would like to do two way binding for reactive form control. Firstly I need to set the value received from @Input data.

Actual result is, when I set static string it is working fine.

**Parent component HTML**

```
<ng-template [ngSwitchCase]="'edit'">
          <app-edit class="flex-auto" (editItem)="disciplineAfterView($event)" [discipline] = "selectedItem"></app-edit>
      </ng-template>
```

**Child component HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="disciplineForm">

      <app-input-multilang [title]="'Discipline'" [form]="disciplineForm" [en]="'discipline_en'" [de]="'discipline_de'">
      </app-input-multilang>

    </form>
```

**Child component TS**

```
 @Input() discipline: any;

this.disciplineForm.get('discipline_de').setValue("dd");  // Working fine

this.disciplineForm.get('discipline_en').setValue(this.discipline.name.en); // Not working
```

Here the @Input **discipline** object values

```
name: {en: "44", de: "44"}
```

Comment: just try `patchValue`

Comment: patchValue not gonna help him.  Please add your html file

Comment: HTML is updated.

Comment: Check if `this.discipline.name.en` is defined in place where you assigning it.

Comment: when does the selectedItem get the value ?

Comment: @Franklin: SelectedItem => sending the  selected object  like name: {en: "44", de: "44"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the form value inside `ngOnChanges()`

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if(changes['discipline']) {
    this.disciplineForm.get('discipline_en').setValue(this.discipline.name.en);
  }
}
```

Comment: This works fine when page load. But I'm looking for dynamically need to update whenever the @Input discipline changes

Comment: @klmuralimohan Then you must set it on ngOnChanges(). Find the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Either you can *write a setter for the input property* and write the setValue once the value is set. Or you can write the setValue inside the `ngOnChanges`.

`ngOnChanges` gets called whenever there is a change in the input property.

eg for ngOnChanges.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if (changes && changes.discipline && changes.discipline.currentValue) {
    this.disciplineForm.get('discipline_en').setValue(this.discipline.name.en);
  }
}
```